# Anonymous class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have heard about anonymous function but the concept of Annynomous class is new to me. for example we have an HOC here which looks like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
   return class extends Component {
     render () {
          return (
               <div className={className}>
                   <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
             </div>
         )
       }
   }
}
```

**[Question]**
Here, I am unable to understand meaning of this line `return class extends Component {` (I know the extends component from React, {component})

Can someone explain me what it does generally? if the description is very vague or brief then do let me know.

Comment: Speaking of classes in javascript in general they are just a "special functions". Syntactic sugar. So you could have class declarations, class expressions (incl. anonymous) as you would have with normal functions.

Comment: Also the fact you could have anonymous class expression doesn't mean you should. It is always good idea to give function names for debugging and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here, I am unable to understand meaning of this line `return class extends Component {`
>
> Can someone explain me what it does generally?

It defines a class that has no name and returns it from the `withClass` function.

That is, it does this, but all in one expression and without giving the class a name:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
   class TheClass extends Component {
     render () {
          return (
               <div className={className}>
                   <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
             </div>
         )
       }
   }
   return TheClass;
}
```

You might use it like this:

```
const MyClass = withClass(SomeComponent, "foo");
```

...which you can then use like this:

```
<MyClass foo="bar"/>
```

...and you'll get

```
<div className="foo">
    <SomeComponent foo="bar" />
</div>
```

...when it is rendered.